# Commerce order delete and order item delete events

Tags: commerce

Quick question I hope someone can easily answer.

There are two order events for order delete listed here: https://github.com/drupalcommerce/commerce/blob/8.x-2.x/modules/order/src/Event/OrderEvents.php

`commerce_order.commerce_order.delete`

and

`commerce_order.commerce_order_item.delete`

I want to delete some related entities when an order line is deleted, so i can hook into commerce_order.commerce_order_item.delete, but my question is if an entire order is deleted will this event also be triggered for each individual line, or do i need to repeat my code also for commerce_order.commerce_order.delete and loop through each line on the order?

Comment: Well... there is one way to find out, are you thinking what I'm thinking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if an entire order is deleted will this event also be triggered for each individual line

Yes it will - the commerce order entity has a `postDelete` method which loops through the order items and deletes them one by one

```
public static function postDelete(EntityStorageInterface $storage, array $entities) {
  parent::postDelete($storage, $entities);

  // Delete the order items of a deleted order.
  $order_items = [];
  /** @var \Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\OrderInterface $entity */
  foreach ($entities as $entity) {
    foreach ($entity->getItems() as $order_item) {
      $order_items[$order_item->id()] = $order_item;
    }
  }
  /** @var \Drupal\commerce_order\OrderItemStorageInterface $order_item_storage */
  $order_item_storage = \Drupal::service('entity_type.manager')->getStorage('commerce_order_item');
  $order_item_storage->delete($order_items);
}
```

Deleteing the order item will invoke the event you're subscribing to, so no need to do anything else.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much.

Comment: I got this all working but I have another problem, I did not relaise that commerce_order.commerce_order_item.delete is fired not just when an order line is deleted, but also when an item is simply removed from the cart. Is there any distinction between deleting a line from a completed order and removing an item from the cart, in terms of a subscribed event? is there another event I should use instead?